# openni_tracker fails with fuerte and Xubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: kinect, ros-fuerte, openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Guys,

I just dual booted Xubuntu 12.04 along side my existing Ubuntu 10.10 install, and proceeded to to a fresh install of fuerte (on 12.04) by following the instructions on the install tutorial.

I then installed openni_kinect (which installs openni_tracker).

I have a Kinect attached (which works fine on 10.10/electric) and fired up the openni_tracker with the command "rosrun openni_tracker openni_tracker".

I get the following error:

"ERROR 1338827753.716401344: Find user generator failed: This operation is invalid!"

I am wondering if I didn't set up my environment properly, or if there is an xml file missing somewhere.

Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Thanks!

Kel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35620/openni_tracker-fails-with-fuerte-and-xubuntu-12.04-lts/) by [Kel](https://answers.ros.org/users/1972/kel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2012-06-04

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-06-04**:
Might you take a look at this? http://ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_follower/Tutorials/Demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I had the same error in a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS running in a MacBook Pro (with dual boot).

I am the third one that has found the same problem, so I have posted it here:
http://answers.ros.org/question/36921/openni_tracker-timeout-error-in-fuerte-ubuntu-1204/

I hope we finally manage to solve it.

---

Originally posted by [Victor Gonzalez-Pacheco](https://answers.ros.org/users/2660/victor-gonzalez-pacheco/) with karma: 396 on 2012-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had this problem. Every time I ran the openni_tracker node it threw a "Find user generator failed: This operation is invalid!"

How I solved it:
Run the ./install.sh from your NITE download. I used NITE-Bin-Dev-Linux-x86-v1.5.2.21

Hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [HammyG](https://answers.ros.org/users/4052/hammyg/) with karma: 51 on 2013-02-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1